# Is npython.exe the only option to run a python script which imports .net dlls with Python.net

Tags: c#, python, .net, serialization, python.net

My codebase is predominantly in .net framework. I am trying to make one of the libraries available in a python script via python.net. I am able to get this to run successfully by

1. Downloading the python.net source code and then building npython.exe/python.runtime.dll from the source
2. Run the python script like this `npython.exe MyPythonScript.py`

Everything works as expected.

However, if don't use my npython version, but use pip to install the pythonnet package directly in my anaconda python, and then try to run the script like `C:\Anaconda3\python MyPythonScript.py`, I get errors like

```
The deserializer cannot load the type to deserialize because type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[RefData.LookUpDataItem, RefData, Version=1.0.6841.27933, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' could not be found in assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Check that the type being serialized has the same contract as the type being deserialized and the same assembly is used.
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserializeInSharedTypeMode(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 declaredTypeID, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContextComplex.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, String name, String ns)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.NetDataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Utility.Deserialize(Byte[][] buffers, Boolean checkTypeToLoad, Object context, IEnumerable`1 knownTypes)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.RoutingClient.SendMsgAndWait(RequestBody reqMsg, IRequestTracker& tracker)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.SendReceive(RequestBody reqMsg, IMonitoringListener listener)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.InternalGet(String key, DataCacheItemVersion& version, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.<>c__DisplayClass49.<Get>b__48()
```

The program retrieves some data from a Microsoft AppFabric cache server. The caching dlls are in the same location. There is no change to my library dlls or the python script using them. Just different invocations.

Same behaviour is observed with both the Ananconda python 3.6 installation and a standalone python 2.7 installation. Is this not possible at all - or is there something specific to caching and serialization that causes the issues ? Any help here would be much appreciated.